# Magento's 1.9.1 theme email-inline.css ignored

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, rwd-theme

I've read other threads about this but not resolution.

Here's how I test it:

- I'm sending a test user a reset-password email.
- The email arrives but without my css (which are simply RTL supporting = dir: rtl; text-align: right; ,etc...)

So far I've checked the following:

- Changing `email-inline.css` from `skin/base/frontend` works.
- The template itself works fine for the website and is compiled from scss.
  (again it's mostly RTL support based on the default rwd scss).

**/skin/rwd/mytemplate**

My `design/rwd/mytemplate` is as follows:

```
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>
</theme>
```

(I've tried changing it)

I've also checked the CSS permissions to be as the one on the base template `email-inline.css` and it didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Need to know your full stack of theme settings.

Answer (score 1):

On my situation my css kicked-in once I've validated that my *General->Design* settings were correct.

```
Current Package Name:
        rwd
CSS:
        mytemplate
Layout:
        mytemplate
Default:
        mytemplate
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it running like this.
The trick was not to use `email-inline.css`. I changed copied the `email-non-inline.css` from base folder to this folder

```
\skin\frontend\rwd\default\css
```

There I did the changes and uploaded it.